# Why does someNum - Math.floor(someNum) give me different decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have some simple javascript which I want to use to determine if a number needs to be rounded.

**Example:** User enters 1.2346 and the number is rounded to 1.235 and a message should be displayed to the user informing them that the number was rounded. 
Rounding the number isn't the issue, but showing the error message to the user is. I need to find the number of digits after the decimal point.

I use the following code to retrieve the decimal places off of a string. I then count the length of the variable to get the decimal places:

`var dp = field_value - Math.floor(field_value);`

However, When I test this I enter `1.23` for the value of `field_value`. When I check the value of field value it is indeed `1.23`. When I check the value of Math.floor(field_value) it is indeed `1`. But then I check the value of dp and it turns out to be `0.22999999999999998`

Why does this subtraction not work the way it is expected?

Comment: The subtraction works exactly as expected--what is wrong is your understanding of how numbers are represented in a computer. They are represented using binary floating point values, and some values that can be represented evenly in decimal cannot be represented evenly in binary. The number 0.23 happens to be one of those values.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I chose the right number to test then :/ Lucky me.

Comment: (Because you deleted your REST question w/o given me a chance to reply.) @Steve I don't know what you're saying. `books/1` is the route for a book with ID 1. The HTTP verb determines the rest: GET retrieves the record. DELETE deletes it. PUT updates it. POST creates it. I don't see what's complicated yet.

Comment: @DaveNewton What does he mean when he says this? "Hypermedia is defined by the presence of application control information embedded within, or as a layer above, the presentation of information. Distributed hypermedia allows the presentation and control information to be stored at remote locations. "  What control information is he embedding with the data? Another websie defined it as URIs for additional information/actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is given by the fact that floating numbers have a finite representation, take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and you will understand how and why.

If problem with roundings is just for printing that number you could use something like [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) for JS that allows you to format float output as you nee.

Comment: Good link. The only thing I would add is an answer to his second question, which can generally be achieved with (''+num).split('.')[1].length

Comment: @BrianCray thats that I tried first, but I ran into an issue if the user entered a whole number

Comment: (num+'.').split('.')[1].length will work whether it's already a float or not

Comment: @BrianCray If you split it on a decimal point it works fine. But if there are no decimal points then the array element 1 doesn't exist and you cannot call length on it or it errors out. I fixed the issue with a little hack job, so that still brought me to a correct solution. Thanks :)

EDIT: I have bad eyes and see that you concatenated a decimal point on it manually, which works also. Thanks - just wish I saw that before

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do anything too exact and specific with the *representation* of a floating point number is always going to a tricky situation.  As other people have pointed out, this is a property of IEEE-754 floating point standard.  Besides treating it as a string and trying to analyze the number, you could also just round it deterministically to the format you want, doing something like:

```
function roundFloat(num, decimalPlaces) {
    multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Rounding it isn't the issue, I have a method for that. I was just running into an issue of figuring out how to determine if I needed to display the message to the user.